# Can i run more than one js script at Node.js startup

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to run an additional script before the main 'node app' is called. So, i have changed my package.json as follows:

```
 "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": ["node helloworld", "node app"]
  },
...
```

Then from command line i run:

```
npm start
```

This doesn't work. Is there way to call one script before the another at Node.js startup? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use an array for the processes.  Separate them with a semicolon instead like this.

```
 "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node helloworld; node app"
  },
...
```

Comment: This works, although I believe this depends on the syntax of your current shell.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something with `child_process`, e.g.

```
// start.js
var cp = require('child_process');

cp.exec("node helloworld", function (err) {
  require("./app");
});
```

And simply:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": ["node start"]
}
```

Comment: Thank you numbers1311407. I am sure this work as well, however. Daniel's response is less code. For learning, would there be any advantages of forking over the Daniel's code example?

Comment: Well, this would give you access to the stderr & stdout of the 1st script, if you needed that.  But otherwise, not really.  Only as pointed out in the comments to @Daniel's answer, that running consecutive scripts this way is making assumptions about the shell.  Pretty sure that wouldn't work in windows, for example.